# Module not found even though I have it installed

Tags: python, numpy, installation, pip

I've tried all of this

```
pip install numpy
pip3 install numpy
python -m pip install numpy
```

and when I try import numpy i just get

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

how do i fix this?

Comment: When you try to install numpy, does it seem to install successfully? What operating system are you running? What version of python?

Comment: im using python 3.9.7, i use windows 10 and when i do the install commands again it says "Requirement already satisfied: numpy in (directory)"